# how to fetch list of users who have taged a list item with "I Like it" tag

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

i want to programatically fetch all users(list of users) who have a tagged a sharepoint 2010 custom list item "i like it".

[this thread shows how to get count of user who have tagged a list item with "I Like it"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/sharepoint2010programming/thread/352380bc-1695-4dbc-8ef6-64afa850befa)

but i want list of users // sharepoint provide this functionality out of the box in central admin [for this follow this link](http://news.lehsys.com/2010/05/tags-notes-and-i-like-it-social-sharepoint-2010/)

is there any way to fetch this information programatically ??

thanks in advance!!

Comment: I did not know that Umbrella Corporation is into mortal software development these days. :)

Comment: hmmmm ..... this is what !! keep it secret....

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at the thread you linked.  It is getting a list, it is just returning the count from the list after that.  The code for getting the list should be sufficient for you.

Comment: that list contains all the tags associated with the list item ...... but it does not give any informaion for list[0] item about the users who have added the tag to it , except the tag owner who has created the tag for the first time in the  in term store.